# Angular ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have encountered an issue in loop (ng-repeat). I used json data for loop data. Its simple and i have uploaded in plunker. Thank you in advance.

```
var app = angular.module('ShippingApp', []);

app.controller('ShippingCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.name = 'World';
$http.get('shippingaddress.json')
   .then(function(res){
      $scope.addresses = res.ShippingAddresses;                
    });
});
```

Comment: The Plunker code is http://plnkr.co/edit/SscKYTxwLwJluuHrIiYX?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `res` contains the `$http` result object, which has a `data` property, which is an Array of one object, so you can do:

```
$scope.addresses = res.data[0].ShippingAddresses;
```

(Use a `console.log(res)` to view your response object, it will make things easier)